# Sort-Object Multiple property -unique

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to Sort a csv file with timestamp 1st and then get unique entry of column cell with the latest entry. How do i do this

```
Timestamp       Cell
28/2/2022       Item1
27/2/2022       Item1
02/3/2022       Item1
01/3/2022       Item2
27/2/2022       Item2
02/3/2022       Item2
```

```
$lookupData | Sort-Object -Property  @{Expression = "Timestamp"; Descending = $true}, @{Expression = "Cell"; Unique = $true} | Export-Csv .\Genios_Alert_Final.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output should only capture

```
Timestamp       Cell
02/3/2022       Item1
01/3/2022       Item2
```

Thanks for the comment.. I managed to get this working with the grouping the cell column and then sorting the timestamp column with descending and picking the 1st

```
$Group_cell = $lookupData | Group-Object -Property Cell
$FinalArray = ForEach ($Client in $Group_cell) {

    $Client.Group | 
    Sort-Object -Property timestamp -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1
}

$FinalArray | Export-Csv .\Genios_Alert_Final.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

but if i have another column say service. how do i first group with service and then sort with cell and then pick the last time stamp.

```
Timestamp       Cell      Service
28/2/2022       Item1     Service1
27/2/2022       Item1     Service1 
02/3/2022       Item1     Service2 
01/3/2022       Item2     Service2 
27/2/2022       Item2     Service3
02/3/2022       Item2     Service3
```

and the expected output like

```
Timestamp       Cell     Service
28/2/2022       Item1     Service1    
02/3/2022       Item1     Service2
02/3/2022       Item2     Service3
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want, `Sort-Object` is doing what you asked for, unique values of the `Cell` column.

Comment: I agree with @SantiagoSquarzon , also descending on the TimeStamp is unlikely to work as expected if you are not type casting to a datetime property. Also I would suggest sorting by the property you want to use the unique on, this will make the sorting of unique items considerably quicker (Process / manipulate data before working on how you want it presented).

Comment: Hi Santiago , CraftyB..  i have updated the query. What i am trying is first group csv file  with Service  and then group with Cell and then pick the latest timestamp.

Comment: HI All, Is there a better way of getting my desired result. Or am i complicating the Group-Object. Any help will he appreciated..